# Substrings from a structure in C

Tags: c

All filenames in my project have a standard format:
NNNN-YYYYMMDD-HHMM.ext

As I use the date & time elements from the filename, can I extract them directly from the structure.

Existing structure:

```
struct linux_dirent {
   long           d_ino;
   off_t          d_off;
   unsigned short d_reclen;
   unsigned char  d_type;
   char           d_name[]; // null-terminated filename
};
```

This pseudo code shows what I would like to achieve:

```
...
   char           d_name[]; {
       char           d_name_date[5, 8];  // would return YYYYMMDD
       char           d_name_time[14, 4]; // would return HHMM
   }
};
```

I can do this by using a function in the structure, but it's a long-winded way to do it.
It is trivial to get the date and time elements from the name in the main program, but I wondered if I was missing a simple alternative from within the structure.

Thank you

If I do this:

```
...
   char           d_name[5];
   char           d_date[9];
   char           d_time[];
}
```

d_name returns the full filename: Cam1-20160131-0530.ima
d_date returns 20160131-0530.ima
d_time returns 0530.ima
These results are 'as expected' as each item is displayed as a string of characters terminating on the same null terminator.

Comment: Where exactly is the problem ? It's simple string manipulations.

Comment: If I understand well what you want, you want to have 3 members in your struct, and 2 of them are pointing directly and automatically to a subpart of the first, just when assigning the first one ? A sort of `union` but on a specific part of memory ? So when you change one of them, others are automatically modified ?

Comment: @Michael Walz  As I said, it's trivial to get the the date/time from filename, but I was interested in knowing if I had missed a simple alternative taking the results directly from the structure.

Comment: @Garf365 Yes - exactly that

Comment: @anita2R I think null terminator will cause some trouble to identify correctly each substring. Secondly, your try use an undefined behavior : you use buffer overflow to automatically assign second and third field => it works here, but not sure anywhere else!

Comment: @anita2R what you want can be done easily in C++. You may consider move to that language. C++ is more or less a superset of C. I don't think there is an alternative to writing three functions that return the strings you want in C.

Comment: @Michael Walz Thanks for the comment on C++. However I have only just started learning C. I do have a working version, so I will accept that what I would have liked to do is not possible in C, but it's not a show-stopper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not possible in `C`. The only choice you have is to use function to extract, set or print (or any other action you need) each part of primary string.

Indeed, string must be null terminated, so, you cannot have a string and a substring at same place : substring cannot be null terminated without modifying primary string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can  copy the  full string in the struct and write zeroes where the `-` and `.` are.

NB just to be clear, if you do this:

```
struct myStruct {
   char           d_name[5];
   char           d_date[9];
   char           d_time[9];
}
```

...generally it will work, but there's no guarantee that the compiler doesn't add padding bytes between the struct members, and in that case you won't get the expected result. And even with no padding, it can still be UB to write the full string in that struct.
It's certainly not worth the risk in real code.

Comment: After reading the full filename, writing nulls back into the filename makes the two substrings return the date/time components. It's a solution but not quite what I was looking for.

Comment: I think it's mandatory to write the zeroes manually. You can't separate the strings otherwise. The interesting issue is the limit between legal and UB.

Comment: It's a dangerous bet. As you say, generally it's work but it's still an UB, just be changing level of optimization of compiler it can brake the soft

Comment: For C++ it's UB, for C as it's all `char` I'm not sure, could be possible to avoid UB with an union (still not worth it anyway).